# Suggest Forecasting Method for irregular time interval

Tags: time-series, forecasting

I have the prevalence rate of stunting for the year 1996, 1999, 2004, 2007, 2011 and 2014.

Now I want to 'forecast' the prevalence rate of stunting for the year "2030"

Which methods/models can I follow to make proper forecasting prevalence for 2030?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: With only six years of data spanning 20 years, your ability to accurately forecast a value 16 more years out is practically nil.  In light of this, the slight irregularity in the dates is of no importance and the meaning of "proper" will depend almost wholly on your *scientific* assumptions about stunting rate.

Comment: Now, please can you tell me, what can I do now in order to forecast?

Comment: I can't tell you anything, nor can anyone else reasonably advise you, because you haven't given us any useful information of the sort I indicated in my comment.

Comment: @whuber  I think it's perfectly clear what Asibul is asking, it's just that the answer is "there's nothing you can reasonably do".

Comment: @Peter That's true in general.  One can conceive, though, of situations in which projection not only is possible, but reasonable.  That's why I have been requesting clarification.

Answer (score 2):

None.  That's my advice. Don't try to project to 2030 from 6 data points.

I am assuming that "stunting" is being used in the sense of children not growing normally due to malnutrition. The problem with any projection from your data is that it's going to assume that a pattern from the past is going to continue, 12 years into the future.  But stunting is going to be affected by a lot of things that are hard to predict and that aren't well accounted for in the data from previous years.